# How to control audio output source in ionic Capacitor

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm tying to create a Call application using Capacitor.

The problem is that when user accepts the call, audio plays on phone's speaker(I mean the out load speaker)

I don't have any control on audio output source.
I want to have a toggle button to switch between audio output source.

Any ideas?

I mean something like this toggle button(WhatsApp):

[image]

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? I am unable to toggle off of speaker even using a custom plugin

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the phone's speaker. In my case, I just added Bluetooth permission to the `AndroidManifest.xml` and it allowed the app to use Bluetooth headphones by default.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```